# Multiple versions of local dependency in Cargo workspace with different features (Rust)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a workspace with 3 packages that depend on a fourth package, also in the workspace. Let's call them A, B, C and D is the package that they all depend on.

Package D has features for conditional compilation, if passed "async-traits" it compiles a set of traits for tokio, if "async-std-traits" for async-std, and if it has neither it compiles traits based on `std::io::{Read, Write}` for regular blocking IO. It then does a blanket impl to give any types which implement these other traits some default functionality. These feature flags are intended to be mutually exclusive.

Individually I can build all these crates just fine. However, when I try to build them in a workspace, or run `clippy --all`, they fail to build on an error saying "the trait bound is not satisfied"

https://github.com/leshow/tokio-i3ipc/blob/master/i3ipc-types/src/lib.rs#L95

```
#[cfg(all(feature = "async-traits", not(feature = "async-std-traits")))]
impl<T: AsyncRead + AsyncWrite> I3Protocol for T {}

#[cfg(all(feature = "async-std-traits", not(feature = "async-traits")))]
impl<T: AsyncStdRead + AsyncStdWrite> I3Protocol for T {}

impl<T: io::Read + io::Write + I3Protocol> I3IPC for T {}

#[cfg(all(not(feature = "async-traits"), not(feature = "async-std-traits")))]
impl<T: io::Read + io::Write> I3Protocol for T {}
```

These are the implementations which seem to conflict in the workspace.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without having looked at the details, I guess you end up with both `async-traits` and `async-std-traits` enabled. Features are additive, and Cargo will enable all features of a specific version of a crate that is requested to be enabled anywhere in the dependency hierarchy.

Comment: Yes exactly, the trait impls are meant to be mutually exclusive. This dependency is inside a workspace with it's dependents. I'm guessing that's not allowed? When I removed the workspace all the sub-crates compiled successfully, I guess because they were then each able to include their own version of the dependency with the correct feature set enabled.

Comment: Cargo's model for features is that they can always be enabled if _any_ depending crate needs them, and that they are orthogonal to each other. Using features in the way you do here – two mutually exclusive features that can't be enabled at the same time – will not only cause the problem you encountered here, but will also break in a similar way when the crate is used in a more complex dependency hierarchy with different crates enabling different features. So it's definitely not recommended to uses features this way.

Comment: Offer the above as an answer?